# jQuery not working for fadeOut

Tags: jquery

I got this code for testing purpose, it's very simple , when I open it in Firefox for debugging, it's not working, everything appears to be loaded and fine, it's very weird, any thoughts on this? . many thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Hover Over effect jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javscript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("img").click(function(event) {
          $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="viewport">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="images/renew.jpg">
      </a>

      <div class="caption"><span>Caption goes here</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you have 2 `<html>` tags?

Comment: You aren't supposed to put it inside `<script type="text/javscript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">`, put your jQuery in a seperate `<script>` afterwards.

Comment: You need another script tag. the contents of the script tag doesn't get run if the source request is successful.

Comment: The script is not within a script tag, you can't latch onto a script tag that has a source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
<script type="text/javscript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("img").click(function(event) {
                $(this).fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });

      </script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("img").click(function(event) {
                $(this).fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });

      </script>
```

When you load an external script using the `src` attribute, the browser will ignore the contents of the `<script>` tag if the request is successful. The solution is easy, just add another script tag.

---

You should also remove the `<html>` that is before your `<!DOCTYPE html>`. It is pointless and wrong. Also, *if* this is the entire document, you need a `</html>` at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with why the code isn't working.

1. When you try to load an external script using the src attribute it will ignore the contents of the script tag. Just include `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>` instead :).
2. You misspelt JavaScript when you created the script element. Amend the spelling mistake and it will fix the code after you've correctly included the jQuery library.

A couple more helpful tips:

- Make sure your html tags are in the correct place. In your code, you've declared the html tag twice. Make sure you have a `<html>` at the top and a closing tag `</html>` at the end.
- The `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration is situated at the very top of the document.

Example using your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Hover Over effect jQuery</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $("img").click(function(event) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
                });
            });

          </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="viewport"><a href="#">
    <img src="robin.gif" ></a>

    <div class="caption"><span>Caption goes here</span></div></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a slim build
get the production version. [here](http://jquery.com/download/)

> You can also use the slim build, which excludes the ajax and effects
>   modules:
>
> Download the compressed, production jQuery 3.3.1 slim build
>
> Download the uncompressed, development jQuery 3.3.1 slim build